# Нужна ли запятая: не позже(,) чем?

Tags: пунктуация

*Не позже чем через полстолетия мир окажется на грани глобальной катастрофы.*

Перед **чем** нужна запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Из справочника по пунктуации:
Примечание 3. Не ставится запятая перед как и чем в оборотах не более как, (не) раньше чем, (не) больше чем и т. п., если они употребляются не при сравнении, например:

Меньше чем через полчаса прибежал запыхавшийся Прохор. 
Шолохов

Я виделся и говорил с ним не далее как месяц тому назад. Вся операция продолжается не больше чем десять-пятнадцать минут.